# Get information of currently playing tracks other than music app in native app objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avaudiosession, mpmusicplayercontroller

I want to detect the currently playing song in my native app as ether is one audio session in app.
I implemented below and when song playing through phone music app, its working fine.

```
-(void)checksession
{
    BOOL isPlayingWithOthers = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying];
    if(isPlayingWithOthers)
    {
        _controller = [MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer];
        [_play setEnabled:YES];
        [_pause setEnabled:YES];
        [_next setEnabled:YES];
        [_prev setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

But if the song is playing from another app like pandora app, then MPMusicPlayerController is not working.
Please suggest how can I control the next, prev, play , pause even if the song is being played via another apps rather than phone music app.

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

• You cannot control the playback of other apps from your own app unless something has drastically changed in iOS11.

• In that same vein, you cannot get info on anything playing unless it is using one of the built-in musicPlayers (systemMusicPlayer, and maybe applicationMusicPlayer)

I have not looked over the changes in iOS11 to see if this has changed.